# how to make group by in listview

Tags: android

i have a custom list view with custom array adapter..
i fill the list view with array that i get from data base...

the problems is = how i can show the list view like distinct in database / group by...
i want to do this from my listview, not my data base because some reason...

here my snipcode

```
public void setListView(){
    int jumlahData = A_BonRokok_Main.count;
    int jumlahDataDetail = A_BonRokok_Main.countDetail;

    Log.d("Jumlah Data : ", ""+jumlahData);
    Log.d("Jumlah Data Detail : ", ""+jumlahDataDetail);

    if(jumlahData > 0){
        tabItemList = new ArrayList<bonrokok_salesplandetail_model>();
        final BonRokok_TabItem_Adapter adapter = new BonRokok_TabItem_Adapter(getActivity(), tabItemList);

        for (int i = 0; i < jumlahDataDetail;  i++) {
            String namaRokok = A_BonRokok_Main.namaRokok[i];
            String jumlah    = A_BonRokok_Main.jumlah[i];
            String satuan    = A_BonRokok_Main.satuan[i];
            tabItemList.add(new bonrokok_salesplandetail_model(namaRokok, Integer.parseInt(jumlah), satuan));

            Log.d("Nama Rokok : ", namaRokok);
            Log.d("Jumlah : ", jumlah);
            Log.d("Satuan : " , satuan);
        }
        listContent.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    else
    {
        tabItemList = new ArrayList<bonrokok_salesplandetail_model>();
        final BonRokok_TabItem_Adapter adapter = new BonRokok_TabItem_Adapter(getActivity(), tabItemList);
        listContent.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

with this code i get data like this

cigar 1 | 10
cigar 2 | 10
cigar 1 | 10
cigar 2 | 10

what i want is just like this

cigar 1 | 20
cigar 2 | 20

Comment: Please post a picture of what you get and what you actually want?

Comment: First you need to check Data repeating or not if it is repeating then plus the value then store in another listview using by loop.

Comment: You're saying you want to consolidate 'like' values, correct? If that's the case, you need to consolidate the data BEFORE passing it to the ListView instead of just adding each one individually. Neither the ListView nor the Adapter can understand that those objects are the same and require consolidation; you have to handle that kind of thing manually.